Diffculties in understanding notations in definition describing multivariable polynomial
The following is taken from Concrete Abstract Algebra by:N. Lauritzen
Background:
Polynomials in several variables should correspond to algebraic expressions like $X^2 + XY + Y + Y^3 = X^5$ (in the case of two variables $X$ and $Y$).  We define the polynomial ring $R[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ in $n$ variables $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ as
$$R[X_1,\ldots,X_n]=R[\Bbb{N}^n]=\{f:\Bbb{N}^n:\to R\mid f(v)=0, |v|\gg 0\},$$
where $v=(v_1\ldots,v_n)\in \Bbb{N}^n$ and $|v|=v_1+\ldots+v_n$.  A polynomial $f\in R[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ is the same as a function $f:\Bbb{N}^n:\to R$ that is non-zero for only finitely many $v\in \Bbb{N}^n$.  We let $X^v\in R[\Bbb{N}^n]$ denote the function given by
$$\begin{equation}
X^v(w)=
    \begin{cases}
        1 & \text{if } v=w,\\
        0 & \text{if } v\neq w,
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}$$
With this notation, every polynomial $f\in R[\Bbb{N}^n]$ can be written as a (finite) sum
$$f=\sum_{v\in \Bbb{N}^n} a_vX^v,$$
where $a_v\in R$ (an element $r\in R$ is identified with the function mapping the zero vector to $r$ and everything else to $0\in R$).  If $f,g\in R[\Bbb{N}^n]$ we define $f+g$ by $(f+g)(v)=f(v)+g(v)$ and $fg$ by the (finite) sum
$$(fg)(v)=\sum_{v_1+v_2=v}f(v_1)g(v_2),$$
where $v_1,v_2\in  \Bbb{N}^n$.  We note that $0\in R$ is the neurtral element for $+$ and that the function $X^{(0,0,\ldots,0)}$, mapping the zero vector in $\Bbb{N}^n$ to $1\in R$ and everythign else to $0$, is the neural element for multiplication.  In the notation $R[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ for $R[\Bbb{N}^n], X_1$ refers to $X^{(1,0,\ldots,0)}, X_2$ to $X^{(0,1,\ldots,0)},\ldots$ and $X_n$ to $X^{(0,\ldots,0,1)}$.
Questions
I am having trouble understanding the two italized passages above:
"(an element $r\in R$ is identified with the function mapping the zero vector to $r$ and everything else to $0\in R$)." $\quad(1)$
and
"We note that $0\in R$ is the neurtral element for $+$ and that the function $X^{(0,0,\ldots,0)}$, mapping the zero vector in $\Bbb{N}^n$ to $1\in R$ and everythign else to $0$, is the neural element for multiplication." $\quad(2)$
For $(1)$, i don't know how the function $f$ maps the zero vector to $r$ and everything else to $0\in R$.  with $\bar{0}=(0,\ldots,0)$  Does the author mean either:
$$\begin{equation}
f(w)=
    \begin{cases}
        \sum_{v\in \Bbb{N}^n} a_vX^v(\bar{0})=\sum_{v\in \Bbb{N}^n} a_vr  & \text{if } w=\bar{0}\\
        \sum_{v\in \Bbb{N}^n} a_vX^v(p)=0 & \text{if } w=p,
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}\quad\quad (3)$$,
But how is $w$ independent of $v$ when there is the indicator function $X^v(w)$?
The wordings for the italized part is even more confusing.  For the neural element $0\in R$ for $+$, does it mean in terms of the identity element.  Does the author meant that in $(f+g)(0)=f(0)+g(0)$, $0,f(0),g(0)$ are all neurtral elements?  Or does $f(0), g(0)$ are only neurtral elements also if $(f+g)(0)=0$.
And for $X^{(0,0,\ldots,0)}$, mapping the zero vector in $\Bbb{N}^n$ to $1\in R$ and everythign else to $0$, is the neural element for multiplication.", it seems the author is describing the following piecewise function:
$$\begin{equation}
X^{(0,0,\ldots,0)}(w)=
    \begin{cases}
        1 & \text{if } {(0,0,\ldots,0)}=w,\\
        0 & \text{if } {(0,0,\ldots,0)}\neq w,
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}\quad (4)$$,
But what does he meant by "is the neutral element for multiplication".  Also, how does the piecewise function in $(4)$ relate to the function in $(3)$ when $w$ in $(3)$ it is independent of $v$, but $w$ is not in $(4)$
Thank you in advance.

Below, I'll call my indeterminates $X_1,...,X_n$; I avoid the "$X^v$"-notation since I think it's more confusing than helpful.
A ring element $a$ is identified with the function $$f_a: \mathbb{N}^n\rightarrow r: \sigma\mapsto\begin{cases}
a & \mbox{ if }\sigma=\overline{0}\\
0_R & \mbox{ otherwise.}\\ 
\end{cases}$$ It's this $f_a$ which is "mapping the zero vector to $a$ and everything else to zero." The point is that the "meaning" of this $f_a$ is the formal sum $$a\cdot X_1^0X_2^0...X_n^0+0\cdot[\mbox{sum of all other monomials}],$$ which intuitively simplifies as hoped to just $a$ since $X_1^0X_2^0...X_n^0=1_R$.
"Neutral element" just means identity, and it should be easy to check that $f_{0_R}$ and $f_{1_R}$ are the additive and multiplicative identities in $R[X_1,...,X_n]$ as claimed. I think that you're just getting tripped up around the $X^v$-notation; hopefully the way I've written things above is clearer.

the function $f_a$ is like an evaluation homomorphism?  $f_a(\sigma)=a \text{ if } \sigma=\bar{0}$ and $0_R$ otherwise.  But what is the relationship between $r$,$a$ and $\sigma$?

@Seth Well, your $r$ is my $a$; I just used a different letter, sorry about that. Meanwhile, $f_a$ is the element of $R[X_1,...,X_n]$ corresponding to $a$, that is, we have a canonical embedding $R\rightarrow R[X_1,...,X_n]$ which sends each $a$ to $f_a$. Finally, $\sigma$ (your $v$) should be thought of as ranging over "types of monomial" - e.g. if $n=3$ then $\sigma=(2,0,1)$ corresponds to $X_1^2X_2^0X_3^1$, or more simply $X_1^2X_3$, and $\sigma=(0,0,0)$ corresponds to the monomial $1$.

so if $\sigma=(2,0,1)$, then $f_r(\sigma)=r=f_a(\sigma)=a, \text{ if } \sigma=\bar{0}$, otherwise $0_R$.  But for the coefficient $a_v=a_\sigma,$ Does $a_{(1,2,3)}=a_1a_2a_3$, where $n=3$?   I just want to make sure because i sometimes see for multivariable polynomials, there is a bunch of elements from the field multiplied together per monomial for their respective coefficients.

@Seth I think you're mixing up elements of the multivariate polynomial ring itself with evaluations of those elements at (tuples of) ring elements, but I'm not quite sure. Do you understand the connection between $a\in R$ and $$a\cdot (X_1^0X_2^0X_3^0)+0\cdot(X_1^1X_2^0X_3^0)+0\cdot(X_1^0X_2^1X_3^0)+...?$$ If so, do you understand how the latter is represented by the function $f_a$ defined in my answer?

$a\in R$ is the elements for the coefficient of each monomial.  But I am just confused when it has $a_v$, because $v$ is a vector, and $X^v$ denotes $X^{(b,c,d)}={X_1}^b{X_2}^c{X_3}^d$, then $a_{(b,c,d)}=a$?  I think having the $v$-vector as subscript on $a$ is a bit confusing.
